# Even I don't know the answer

Tags: riddle

(This is the question talking)

```
Even I don't know the answer,

Until I am posted.

All I know is the length,

5 characters that is.

Random it is,

But less than the 64 base youtube id.

This is what identifies me.
```

What is he talking about? What is the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing it's

> The ID number of this post in puzzling.se

Even I don't know the answer,
Until I am posted.

> The ID is only generated on posting

All I know is the length, 
5 characters that is.

> The SE id fits the length, consisting of 5 digits.

Random it is,
But less than the 64 base youtube id.
This is what identifies me.

> The ID is what identifies this post, though it's less complex than youtube's.

which means it's

> **57694**, from `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57694/even-i-dont-know-the-answer`

Comment: Do note that i don't think it's actually random. SE's IDs are actually given sequentially to both questions and answers, so it's actually pretty different from youtube!

Comment: I don't know if someone posts a question (or 2) in the time I am typing , so it is kind of random (although varying just between 2-3 numbers)

Comment: It is still not random. The fact that you can't predict the value doesn't mean that the value is random.